# Problems with C strings and atoi function

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, atoi

I'm working on a program that requires the user to enter a C string of numbers, my program will then convert the `characters` to `ints` and then sum them.

However, when I run it, my program is multiplying the number provided by the number of digits there, **i.e:** if I put `123` it returns `369` or `123*3` or `123+123+123`. It is summing the whole C string , instead of adding one element of the string at a time like I am trying to get it too.

When I try to do `sum+=atoi(numbers[i]);` it tells me that it can't convert `char` to `const char*`, however with it just as `sum+=atoi(numbers);` it is doing the whole string.

Please explain how to do this properly for myself and others.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int SIZE=9000;   //max size of c string
    char numbers[SIZE];    //declare an char array
    int sum=0;             //initialize at 0
    cout << "Enter a series of single digit numbers with nothing separating them.\n";
    cout << "And I will tell you sum of those single digits\n";

    //prompt user

    cin.getline(numbers,SIZE);
    //get input

    //for loop till the end of the string
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(numbers);i++)  
    {
        sum+=atoi(numbers);   
        //if i put "atoi(numbers[i]);" then it tells me I 
        //can't convert char to const char*
    }

    cout << "The sum of these single digits is "<< sum <<endl;  //display result
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use atoi for this. On the vast majority of implementations you can `sum+=numbers[i] - '0';` Most modern character encodings store the numbers in a row starting at '0'. `'0' - '0' = 0`,`'1' - '0' = 1` etc...

Comment: @user4581301, it actually makes little difference what most modern encodings do, the standard actually *mandates* that this must be so.

Comment: Currently my professor is going over c strings, I'm trying to use the atoi function correctly, any suggestions, i got it to work using the -'0' technique however its not in my book or we havent reached it yet , can you please explain a little further about who i can get this issue of atoi fixed? Or will it not work because i have an array of characters and not a string?

Comment: @paxdiablo Groovy. One less thing to worry about. I knew it was safe in EBCDIC, and every other encoding I know of but wasn't willing to go the distance.

Comment: @CaliBreeze, if you *really* want to keep using this method rather than `digitChr - '0'`, I've expanded my answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
sum+=atoi(numbers);
```

three times. Of course you get `sum` as `123+123+123`.

What you need to do is convert each character to a number by subtracting `'0'` from the character.

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(numbers); i++)
{
   char c = numbers[i];
   if ( isdigit(c) )
   {
      sum += (c - '0');
   }
   else
   {
      // Deal with the case when character is not a digit.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if i put "atoi(numbers[i]);" then it tells me i cannot conver char to const char*

That is true. It's because dereferencing a `char` pointer will give you a `char`. And, since `atoi` wants a C-style string, that should be an array of characters terminated with a `\0` (or the address of the first character of that array).

So you *could* take the character and make a string out of it but there's probably a better way:

```
sum += numbers[i] - '0';
```

This will take the actual character at the given position and subtract the character `'0'` from it. Assuming it's a digit character will mean you will get the integer equivalent, a number between `0` and `9` inclusive, which you can then add to the sum.

---

If you *must* use `atoi`, the method will be as follows:

- copy the character into a separate string area.
- append the terminator.
- use `atoi`.

The loop that would do this goes something like:

```
// Create buffer and terminate string.

char str[2];
str[1] = '\0';

// Loop over all characters.

for (int i = 0; i < strlen (numbers); i++) {
    // Make string from character, str[1] stays as '\0'.

    str[0] = numbers[i];

    // Use atoi on that string.

    sum += atoi (str);   
}
```